# How to debug failed container host port mapping

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I am trying to assign a hostPort to the container (some thing `docker run -p 40405:40405`) in golang on a bridge network `my-network.`

Go Code

```
   hostBinding := nat.PortBinding{
        HostIP:   "0.0.0.0",
        HostPort: hostPort,
    }
    containerPortProtocol := nat.Port(containerPort + "/TCP")
    portBinding := nat.PortMap{containerPortProtocol: []nat.PortBinding{hostBinding}}
    
        hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
            NetworkMode: container.NetworkMode(networkName),
            PortBindings: portBinding,
        }
  // no expose port being add
```

Container started. But the network port mapping is not correct. Here is how `docker container inspect` looked like

```
"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "my-network",
            "PortBindings": {
                "40405/TCP": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "40405"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Config/ contianer config

```
"Config": {
            "Hostname": "56c381f43da9",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "40405/tcp": {}
            },
```

Network settings got port number `49158`

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
                "Bridge": "",
                "SandboxID": "7431c421c3602ae7cdd1c30953b557db7bc44b0800702100d8fbb4e94708b782",
                "HairpinMode": false,
                "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
                "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "Ports": {
                    "40405/tcp": [
                        {
                            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                            "HostPort": "49158"
                        }
                    ]
                }

    "Networks": {
                    "my-network": {
                        "IPAMConfig": null,
                        "Links": null,
                        "Aliases": [
                            "56c381f43da9"
                        ],
                        "NetworkID": "d2b9b396ff63110433c88637fb1ea193b51731af304fdb1c35be7ae2be8d5865",
                        "EndpointID": "0b6afb110d7ace8461035f7aaa822856e0f87d77fdc21ab266de638df25abb07",
                        "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                        "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                        "IPv6Gateway": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                        "DriverOpts": null
                    }
                }

I was expecting `40405` to be present in the network settings. But unfortunately its assigning a random port , which is `49158` in our case.
```

Network inspect `docker network inspect my-network`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "my-network",
        "Id": "544ffaa476631d6e86396438988b37e3be91ad1923d2238ed24015b3ae07d870",
        "Created": "2023-02-27T15:00:20.372991761+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
                "56c381f43da9c66d8f431395cefc38589b0ee2d37ef9a59b103c15312d716733": {
                    "Name": "dockerdaemon_daemon-py",
                    "EndpointID": "0b6afb110d7ace8461035f7aaa822856e0f87d77fdc21ab266de638df25abb07",
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                    "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                    "IPv6Address": ""
                }
            },
            "Options": {},
            "Labels": {}
        }
    ]
```

I used
`netstat -tuln | grep 40405`  to check if the port is already taken or being used. Also tried and `sudo journalctl -u docker.service` to see logs. But it looked free and i do not see any logs in particular to the port. So I am not sure what caused it to assign a random port on the network settings.

Comment: The Docker-side networking and published ports are two separate layers.  I wouldn't usually look at the `docker inspect` output in this much detail; can you connect to port 40405 on the host?  What is the actual `docker run` command?  How does the application code set up its network listener?

Comment: It looks like you published the port with `-p 49158:40405`. Can you connect to the host port 49158? Or if you are connecting between containers, can you connect to 40405? What steps did you take to verify the application inside the container is listening on that port?

Comment: @DavidMaze. It looks like In golang docker client, I need to bindPort in hostConfig and also expose the same in containerConfig. Although I have EXPOSE 404045 command in Dockerfile.  I thought that manual expose of port is not necessary in go code and it is mentioned in Dockerfile

Comment: You mention some Go code in a couple of places, and it seems essential to the question.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with my go code.

1. Not using `ExposedPorts` in Container config
2. string `TCP/UDP` should be lower case like tcp/upd

When exposing a port, you need to use both `container.Config` to expose the port within the container and `container.HostConfig` to bind it to the host's port.

wrong piece of code

```
   hostBinding := nat.PortBinding{
        HostIP:   "0.0.0.0",
        HostPort: hostPort,
    }
    containerPortProtocol := nat.Port(containerPort + "/TCP")
    portBinding := nat.PortMap{containerPortProtocol: []nat.PortBinding{hostBinding}}
    
        hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
            NetworkMode: container.NetworkMode(networkName),
            PortBindings: portBinding,
        }
  // no expose port being add
```

Right Code

```
hostBinding := nat.PortBinding{
        HostIP:   "0.0.0.0",
        HostPort: hostPort,
    }

    containerPortProtocol := nat.Port(containerPort + "/tcp")
    portBinding := nat.PortMap{containerPortProtocol: []nat.PortBinding{hostBinding}}

    hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
        NetworkMode: container.NetworkMode(networkName),
        PortBindings: portBinding,
    }

    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image:        image,
        ExposedPorts: nat.PortSet{containerPortProtocol: struct{}{}},
    }, hostConfig, nil, nil, "")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
```

If `EXPOSE` cmd is present in `Dockerfile` then `ExposedPorts` is not required in golang. But you forgot to `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile. Then it is necessary to perform `ExposedPorts` in container config